# How to change the line of a circle

Tags: python

It succeeded in drawing a circle of 100, 80, and 60 people in radius. However, I am trying to change the line of a circle to a dotted line, but I don't know where to put the function. Ask for advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
import turtle

aaa = turtle.Turtle()
aaa.speed(10)

def DotCircle(*x_val):
  x=x_val[0]
  y=x_val[1]
  r=x_val[2]
  for kk in range(1):
    aaa.penup()
    aaa.goto(x,y)
    number_of_dots = 50
    for i in range(number_of_dots):
      aaa.circle(r, 360/number_of_dots)
      aaa.dot()


DotCircle(0,0,100)
DotCircle(0,20,80)
DotCircle(0,40,60)
```

Docs link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle

note that now the dots are not created while the turtle walks in       `aaa.circle(r, 360/number_of_dots)` nut explicitly by calling `aaa.dot()`

Comment: It was a great help. How can I edit the spacing of all three circles of dots to be the same?